# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run a dbtest but I get the following error :

> "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;"

And because of that I also get the following error:

> "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'personRepository' defined in class path
>   resource [root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource [root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;

So we have to take alook at my root-context file and it look the following :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components

     <bean id="personService" class="se.lowdin.civilforsvaret.webapp.services.PersonServiceImpl" />
     -->

     <bean id="personRepository" class="se.lowdin.civilforsvaret.webapp.repositories.PersonRepositoryJpa" />


    <!-- Database -->
        <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/civilforsvaret11" />
        <property name="username" value="bla" />
        <property name="password" value="bla" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Entity Manager -->
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="civilforsvaret" />
        </bean>

        <!-- Transaction Manager -->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>

</beans>
```

And the `persisence.xml` looks the following :

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="civilforsvaret" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <properties>
                        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
                        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
                        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And this is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>se.lowdin</groupId>
    <artifactId>civilforsvaret</artifactId>
    <name>civilforsvaret-webbapp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- MySql connection -->

          <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.174</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am a complete noob with Spring MVC and cant find the problem.

Comment: The problem is not relevant to Spring MVC, it is just your Spring / JPA setup, not the MVC layer

Answer (score 18):

This sounds like a ClassLoader conflict. I'd bet you have the javax.persistence api 1.x on the classpath somewhere, whereas Spring is trying to access [`ValidationMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ValidationMode.html), which was only introduced in JPA 2.0.

Since you use Maven, do `mvn dependency:tree`, find the artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And remove it from your setup. (See [Excluding Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions))

AFAIK there is no such general distribution for JPA 2, but you can use this Hibernate-specific version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

OK, since that doesn't work, you still seem to have some JPA-1 version in there somewhere.
In a test method, add this code:

```
System.out.println(EntityManager.class.getProtectionDomain()
                                      .getCodeSource()
                                      .getLocation());
```

See where that points you and get rid of that artifact.

---

Ahh, now I finally see the problem. Get rid of this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

and replace it with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

On a different note, you should set all test libraries (spring-test, easymock etc.) to

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

Comment: @Josef That would require you telling us more about your project setup. Do you use Maven or Ant or another build system?

Comment: @Josef ok, added some more info

Comment: thank but didnt help stil same error mesage after adding this to my pom.xml <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @Josef ok, added some more info

Comment: The problem is it never comes into the test method and therefore it never writes out anything from the system.out.print in the console It just prints out failed application context then the causes which I cpoied above in my post

Comment: @Josef then do that from a different test class that's not run by spring

Comment: Aight, I got this now : "em : file:/C:/Users/Josef/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar" Also I added my pom.xml file in the post above.

Comment: hmm, but that sounds good. are you sure you are getting the same error as above?

Comment: Problem solved. Or I got another exception to work with. + 5 points for you,

Answer (score 1):

Adding dependencies didn't fix the issue at my end.

The issue was happening at my end because of "additional" fields that are part of the "@Entity" class and don't exist in the database.

I removed the additional fields from the @Entity class and it worked.