# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' when running Fat Jar

Tags: java, maven

I have a core project which contains data and business layers. This project can then be referenced by web applications, batch applications and so on ...

When building my web apps to WAR, everything works as expected. However when building a Fat Jar, which is running my batch processes I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/company/core/configuration/EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at com.company.batch.application.Application.main(Application.java:25) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
        at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLogf(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:81) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Logger.java:553) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:53) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.packageForName(JavaReflectionManager.java:147) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.packageInfo(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:128) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.getTypeMetadataFor(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:111) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:373) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:66) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:52) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:588) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
11:00:11.695 [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] DEBUG c.m.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@2cb9d186 closed by a client.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: DEBUG -- CLOSE BY CLIENT STACK TRACE
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:646) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:259) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:619) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/company/core/configuration/EntityManagerFactoryConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1024) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
 failed; nested exception is java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1049) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.destroyResource(BasicResourcePool.java:1010) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$100(BasicResourcePool.java:44) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$5.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1260) [batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)11:00:11.703 [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] DEBUG c.m.v.c.i.C3P0PooledConnecti

onPool - Successfully destroyed PooledConnection: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@2cb9d186
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
11:00:11.704 [Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()] DEBUG c.m.v.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@2cb9d186
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at com.company.batch.application.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLogf(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:81)
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Logger.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.util.StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.classForName(StandardClassLoaderDelegateImpl.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.packageForName(JavaReflectionManager.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.packageInfo(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.getTypeMetadataFor(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:373)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:588)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 13 more
```

I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799179/2767835

And I think i'm getting conflicting packages when building the Fat Jar, but i cannot figure out what is conflicting.

Here is my dependency tree:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ batch ---
com.company:batch:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- com.company:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.1.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.3.8.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
|  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.8.Final:compile
|  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
|  |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
|  |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.4.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:5.2.0.Final:compile
|  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:jar:5.2.0.Final:compile
|  |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.10.4:compile
|  |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.4:compile
|  |     \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:jar:4.10.4:compile
|  |        \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.4:compile
|  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-infinispan:jar:5.2.0.Final:compile
|  |  \- org.infinispan:infinispan-lucene-directory:jar:7.2.0.Final:compile
|  |     \- org.infinispan:infinispan-core:jar:7.2.0.Final:compile
|  |        +- org.infinispan:infinispan-commons:jar:7.2.0.Final:compile
|  |        +- org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
|  |        +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
|  |        \- org.jboss.marshalling:jboss-marshalling-osgi:jar:1.4.10.Final:compile
|  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.7.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.9.2.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.4:compile
|  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.15:compile
|  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:2.1.3:compile
|  |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.9.0.Final:compile
|  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
|  |  \- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.0.2:compile
|  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:jar:2.1.2:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:0.7.3:compile
|  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
|  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
|  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.5.1:compile
|  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
|  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.5:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
|  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0:compile
|  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
|  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
|  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
|  +- org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
|  +- javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1:compile
|  +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:compile
|  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
|  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:compile
|  \- com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:jar:1.2.1:compile
+- com.company:company-dto:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
+- com.company:company-shared:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.4.1:compile
|  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
|  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
|  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
|  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:7.0.6:compile
|  +- com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:jar:1.15:compile
|  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.14:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.10:compile
|  |     +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:compile
|  |     +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.11:compile
|  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
|  |        \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
|  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.2:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
|  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|     +- com.ibm.jbatch:com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi:jar:1.0:compile
|     |  \- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
|     +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
|     |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
|     |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
|     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
|     \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
|        \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
\- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
   +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
   \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
```

And pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <spring-boot-version>1.2.3.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-dto</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-shared</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.company.batch.application.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Code requested in comments:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.company.batch", "com.company.core", "com.company.shared"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .web(false)
                .run(args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private IConsumerFactory consumerFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        String processType = strings[0];
        String processName = strings[1];

        if(processType != null && !processType.isEmpty() && processName != null && !processName.isEmpty()) {
            if (processType.toLowerCase().equals("-c") || processType.toLowerCase().equals("-consumer")) {
                IConsumer consumer = consumerFactory.getConsumerByQueueName(processName);
                consumer.start();
            } else if (processType.toLowerCase().equals("-st") || processType.toLowerCase().equals("-scheduledtask")) {
                Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler)applicationContext.getBean(processName);
                scheduler.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I have narrowed it down to these two packages or the code use by these. It works after i removed everything that has to do with Search.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

At some point during the initiation of the entityManagerFactory a search index was created.

However why this fails when running the fat jar and not when running the war on tomcat i have no idea. Also everything works in debug with search included.

Comment: Looks like you have an problem in your Logging configuration `Caused by: java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'`

Comment: I have Added some more Exception

Comment: can you post the code from `at com.company.batch.application.Application.main(Application.java:25)
`

Comment: line 25 is ".run(args);"

Comment: I have updated my question. It seems to be hibernate search that causes the problems.

Comment: Setting hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners to false, stopped the problem. Now I just need to figure out if our webapp can do searches.