# Spring "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'"

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I've just started learning about Spring, and decided to follow [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/) tutorial from Spring, but when I try to run my project I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.reactspringresttutorial.payroll.Employee
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at com.reactspringresttutorial.payroll.ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.main(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
```

I have tried to follow the suggestions I found in similar stack-overflow questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799074/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory), but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing. 
Any help would be very appriciated!

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.unicorn</groupId>
<artifactId>react-spring-rest-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>react-spring-rest-tutorial</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.java:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactAndSpringDataRestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseLoader.java:**

```
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final EmployeeRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseLoader(EmployeeRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        this.repository.save(new Employee("Frodo", "Baggins", "Ring bearer"));
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java:**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

**Employee.java:**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String description;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String description) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after starting from the beginning of the tutorial again!

It seems I accidentally added the wrong import for the `@Id`-tag in `Employee.java`:

```
private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
```

I chose `@Id` from `org.springframework.data.annotation` wich was **wrong**, and after I replaced it with `@Id` from `javax.persistence.Id` wich **works**!

And ofcourse, I also made it impossible for anyone but me to see this mistake as I didn't include my `import`-statements in my question. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `EmployeeRepository` with `@Repository`
If that doesnt work, maybe your configuration file is not right. Can you print your `application.properties` file?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding! I tried adding `@Repository`, but no luck. I added `application.properties` to my original post ^^

Comment: Oh! I guess they forgot to mention that in the tutorial...... Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: On second look, I don't think it will help (that is also why I deleted my response), because when you have h2 in your classpath, spring auto-configures that for you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: But this link might help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: Hey! I figured it out. Nothing you could have seen as I explain in my answer, but thanks for taking the time! :)